# jQuery UI slider with two handles - get initial data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery slider with two handles and I need two open their tooltips on initialize.

```
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
    var curValue = ui.value ;
    var tooltip = htmltext;
    $(ui.handle).html(tooltip);

};
$("#slider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1500000,
    values: [30000, 150000],
    create: showTooltips, 
    slide: sliderTooltip
```

When slider created, I need to get values of handles and put them into tooltips. But how can I get values of each one? As far as I can see 'ui' object is empty on initialize until siled changed. I've also tried to trigger slider change event like this:

```
$('#slider').trigger('slidechange');
```

or

```
$('#slider').trigger('change')
```

But it seems that it had no effect. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/OFUMUCO/1/edit).

I use `create` event to attach tooltips. See the code.

When slider is created we get elements like:

```
<div id="slider" style="margin:50px" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 2%; width: 8%;"></div>
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 2%;">
        <div class="ui-slider-tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: -25px; left: -25px;"></div>
    </a>
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 10%;">
        <div class="ui-slider-tooltip" style="position: absolute; top: -25px; left: -25px;"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

`div` elements for tooltips are the same without any information which could differentiate them so you have to get them over parent element. I used

```
$(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle')[i]
```

and `firstChild` to reach the specific tooltip and set proper value.

Most probably there is more elegant way to do that.